# Callback not firing for a getJSON call within a callback of a different getJSON call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest

I am trying to call $.getJSON within the callback of a separate $.getJSON call, but for some reason the second getJSON call is not actually firing, or something else is wrong.  When I step through it the second getJSON gets hit, but it's callback doesn't fire.  here is my code:

```
  var success = '';
  $.getJSON('http://myRestAPI&callback=?', null, function (data) {
    success = data;    
    if(success){
       $.getJSON('http://myRestAPI&callback=?', null, function (data2) {
          success = data2;    
          if(success){
            alert('success');
          }
          else {
            alert('fail');
          }
        });
    }
    else {

    }
  });
```

Is this type of thing not allowed?

Comment: This is perfectly allowable.  There must be something else wrong in your actual implementation.  Are you aware of same-origin ajax restrictions?  Did you set up error handling that could catch ajax errors and tell you what might be going wrong with the 2nd call?

Comment: What you are doing should work, just keep in mind that success won't contain a value on the line after the last `});`

Answer (score 0):

This should work if your ajax call is working fine. I created an example for you at this JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/V3mJp/

Like jfriend00 said, setting up error handling for the Ajax call may give you more insight.

Sorry this is posted as an answer, I am not able to comment yet.